# How to access count property of a dynamic type in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

I have the follow method that returns a dynamic object representing an `IEnumerable<'a>` ('a=anonymous type) :

```
    public dynamic GetReportFilesbyStoreProductID(int StoreProductID)
    {
        Report report = this.repository.GetReportByStoreProductID(StoreProductID);

        if (report == null || report.ReportFiles == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var query = from x in report.ReportFiles
                    orderby x.DisplayOrder
                    select new { ID = x.RptFileID, Description = x.LinkDescription, File = x.LinkPath, GroupDescription = x.ReportFileGroup.Description };

        return query;
    }
```

I want to be able to access the `Count` property of this `IEnumerable` anonymous type. I'm trying to access the above method using the following code and it is failing:

```
        dynamic Segments = Top20Controller.GetReportFilesbyStoreProductID(StoreProductID");

        if (Segments.Count == 0)  // <== Fails because object doesn't contain count.
        {
            ...
        }
```

- How does `dynamic` keyword operate?
- How can I access the `Count` property of the `IEnumerable` anonymous type?
- Is there a way I can use this anonymous type or do I have to create a custom object so that I can pass back a strongly-typed `IEnumerable<myObject>` instead of `dynamic`?

I'd prefer to not do that if I can as this method is only called in one place and creating a throw-away object seems like overkill.

Comment: You should **strongly** consider creating *real* types instead of anonymous types and return an `IEnumerable` of that.  Using dynamic for this purpose annihilates all the advantages of static typing.

Comment: @Kirk Reports could be dynamic? not exactly in this case but still

Comment: When you're defining a one-off type just to pass back from a method, there are very few, if any advantages to static typing.

Comment: @Kirk, This custom object would be a throw-away object that gets used once. Would there be a better option than building out an entire class to use one time?

Comment: @Chevex, if the OP is returning this value from a **public** method I fail to see why we think it will only be called once.

Comment: @kirk, well I have special insight as he is my co-worker. It will only be called once.

Comment: @mquander, I totally disagree that there are no advantages to static typing even in one-off situations.  If you are suggesting it would be nice if you could return anonymous types (as that type) from a method, I agree!  But you can't.  And static typing is *still* endlessly useful in this situation.  (intellisense, compile-time safety, etc.)

Comment: Have to agree with @Kirk here. If this method were private, returning an anonymous type sequence dynamically is reasonable. However, it's public.

Comment: @True, not to be argumentative, but I don't think **dynamic** should *ever* be used to chain an anonymous type along.  It should never be used because one is too lazy to create a proper type.  It should be used for reflection, or dynamic dispatch, or COM, or dynamic scripting.

Comment: If you notice, he does not ask how it *should* be used. He asks how to use dynamic in this instance. Whether or not it's the proper choice is irrelevant. He will likely end up statically-typing it anyway, but the answer to the question is still interesting.

Comment: @Chevex, yes, and that's why these are comments and not answers. :)

Comment: I find it unusual that people are so picky about when `dynamic` is used and isn't used; I get by just fine writing Javascript, Clojure, et al where (gasp) everything is dynamic!  However, I agree that it's not idiomatic C# to use `dynamic` in this situation.  I would personally make a one-off named type or move things around to eliminate the necessity of doing this.

Comment: @mquander, by that logic, why not dispense with `var` and named types and use `dynamic` for every type declaration you have?

Comment: @Kirk - I've encountered one scenario where it makes sense. You have a LONG Linq-to-Objects statement that uses anonymous types for joins (because of property equality). You want to refactor this, but can't Extract Method because of the anonymous types. You'd not only have to create a class but override Equals and GetHashCode.

Comment: @Kirk:  Because the resulting C#-without-types language would suck compared to other modern dynamic languages, and I suspect it would wind up performing poorly in comparison as well. That doesn't really form an argument against isolated uses of `dynamic` to work around awkward bits of C#, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IEnumerable<T>` that's returned from that method doesn't have a `Count` property, so I don't know what you're talking about.  Maybe you forgot to write `ToList()` on the end to reify it into a list, or you meant to call the `Count()` method on `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: There may be no static `Count` property, but there is the `Count()` LINQ extension. I think his point is that he doesn't know how to use the dynamic object that comes back.

Comment: Well, he'd be using it correctly, if he happened to be referring to a property or method that actually exists, so he must have just mixed something up.

Comment: Ah true, I will inform him to add parenthesis to the Count call.

Answer (score 28):

You'll need to explicitly call Enumerable.Count().

```
IEnumerable<string> segments =
  from x in new List<string> { "one", "two" } select x;

Console.WriteLine(segments.Count());  // works

dynamic dSegments = segments;

// Console.WriteLine(dSegments.Count());  // fails

Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Count(dSegments));  // works
```

See [Extension method and dynamic object in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c) for a discussion of why extension methods aren't supported by dynamic typing.

*(The "d" prefix is just for the example code - please do not use Hungarian notation!)*

**Update:** Personally I'd go with [@Magnus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285575/how-to-access-count-property-of-a-dynamic-type-in-c-4-0/6285642#6285642) of using `if (!Segments.Any())` and return `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Comment: +1 Totally forgot about the considerations when using Dynamics. Really wonder how did the accepted answer worked. Thanks though

Comment: perfect.. +++++++

Answer (score 2):

`Count()` needs to enumerate to complete collection, you probably want:

```
if (!Segments.Any()) 
{
}
```

And your function should return `IEnumerable<object>` instead of dynamic

Comment: +1 - I had to try it, but this works. Although I suspect the OP will want to return IEnumerable<dynamic> in order to get at the properties of the anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Linq count`using System.Linq;` Segments.Count()

Answer (score 0):

You could use the property Length too!

```
if (!Segments.Length)
{
    `enter code here`
}
```