# Why do extension methods fail to get resolved for dynamic types?

Tags: c#-4.0, extension-methods, dynamic-keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extension method and dynamic object in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp)

For example:

```
var obj = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
dynamic dobj = obj;

dobj.Count(); // fails
Enumerable.Count(dobj); // works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because knowing which extension method to call requires knowing what the source code looked like before it was compiled (including knowing which `using` directives were present). At runtime this information is not available. The workaround you are using is a good approach.

Comment: Right, so extension methods are syntactic sugar. Makes sense, cheers.