# Possible to order a dynamic type?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have the code below:

```
dynamic myData = GetMyData();
foreach(dynamic d in myData.data)
{
   Console.WriteLine(d.name);
}
```

How could I writeout all of the names in alphabetical order?  If I were using something like `List<MyClass>` i would just use `myData.OrderBy(t => t.name)`, but this does not seem to work when I'm using a dynamic type.

Any suggestions to how I can order these values?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic at all? What's wrong with `var myData = GetMyData().OrderBy(t => t.name);`?

Comment: I am using the Facebook C# SDK and the examples they give all make use of `dynamic`.  This is my first exposure to `dynamic` types, so I can't speak intelligently about why or why not they should be used in this situation.  To be honest I'm not quite sure how dynamic and anonymous types differ, but that's a whole different post.   I do plan on researching the subject some more, but for now I'd just like to know if this can be done.  If not, no big deal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extension method and dynamic object in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Enumerable.OrderBy(myData, (Func<dynamic, dynamic>)(t => t.name));
```

That should return the same as `myData.OrderBy(t => t.name)` would normally.

Since `OrderBy` is an extension method, it won't work on dynamic types. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311527/785745).

Comment: Trying that causes this error: "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: I added a cast. See if it helps.

Comment: Now it gives a `RuntimeBinder` exception: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<object,object>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>, System.Func<object,object>)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `t` has a `name` property? (case-sensitive) I tested with a list of strings, and the `Length` property worked.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct. I had structured it exactly like the OP and forgot to remove the `.data` from `mydata`

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> sequence = Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>(myData);
foreach (var result in sequence.OrderBy(x => x.name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.name);
}
```

Basically after the call to `Cast<dynamic>` and the conversion to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, you can do what you like as a sequence rather than a single value.

Not that I've actually *tried* the above, but I believe it should work.