# Extending Simple.Data with assertions

Tags: c#, assertions, simple.data, fluent-assertions

I'm using this very nice mini ORM, **Simple.Data**, to setup a lot of test data, quick and easy.
I would really like to extend it for assertions. For example i would like to assert on count:

```
Db.MyTable.GetCount(); <- Returns a dynamic
```

So that I could evaluate more or less like you would do with FluentAssertions.
It could look like this:

```
Db.MyTable.GetCount().ShouldBe(X);
```

But I'm finding it very hard to do this **without loosing the advantage of dynamics**.

Does anyone have a hint of how this could be done or if its even possible within reason?

I'm currently traversing the src at GitHub trying to find a way i can do this locally and toying around with **[impromptu](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/)** to find a way.

Comment: I think the question needs to make clear that as far as the compiler is concerned, the return value from GetCount() is dynamic, so extension methods can't be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no happy answer to this. Dynamic and extension methods do not mix, as explained by Jon S and Eric L here: [Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp)

The answer, as in that question, is either to invoke ShouldBe as a static method:

```
AssertionExtensions.ShouldBe(Db.MyTable.GetCount(), 3);
```

or to inline-cast the method's return value to the known type:

```
((int)Db.MyTable.GetCount()).ShouldBe(3);
```

Or, as you are investigating, to use Impromptu to apply an interface to MyTable with a GetCount method. I'm guessing you've seen my blog post on Simple.Data and Impromptu, but if you haven't: http://blog.markrendle.net/2012/10/12/howto-dial-up-the-static-on-simple-data/

Comment: Thank you and yes i've read about impromptu on your blog. Inline casting seems to be the way to go then. I wonder why inline casting didn't it even cross my mind... Thank you for a great product by the way :).

Answer (score 0):

In the classes you are creating why dont you create your own custom assertion class and make the object classes you are creating inherit from them.

```
public class MyClass : MyCustomExceptionClass
{

}
```

In that way it would be easier for you to test the methods in the way you want