# Database.Query return type should be IEnumerable<dynamic>

Tags: c#, dynamic, ienumerable, webmatrix

I need help to understand this thing. Why in the following code the variables "ejes" and "habilidades" are resolved as "dynamic" and the third as `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. This is affecting the code that runs next, an exception appears when I try to invoke the extension method "Count()" because "ejes" and "habilidades" are not IEnumerable. They are the result of the same method "Database.Query".

Here is the snippet:

```
var db = Database.Open("froned");
db.Execute("begin transaction");

try
{
  var asignacion = db.QuerySingle("select * from asignacion_avanza where id_asignacion = @0", id_asignacion);

  var ejes = db.Query(String.Format(@"
                                  select id_eje
                                    from asignatura_eje_nivel
                                   where id_nivel = {0}
                                     and id_asignatura = {1}",
                                       asignacion.id_nivel,
                                       asignacion.id_asignatura));

  var habilidades = db.Query(String.Format(@"
                                  select id_habilidad
                                    from asignatura_habilidad_nivel
                                   where id_nivel = {0}
                                     and id_asignatura = {1}",
                                       asignacion.id_nivel,
                                       asignacion.id_asignatura));
  var dificultades = db.Query("select id_dificultad from dificultad");

  var c_dif = dificultades.Count();
  var c_eje = ejes.Count();
  var c_habilidades = habilidades.Count();
```

I put an Image of the debugger to show the runtime type of the variables.

[image: Extrange return type]

Comment: Awesome having a dark theme for VS2012. You should put the link of your picture in your question, it's hard to read that small of text from the image (and i'm too lazy to view source).

Comment: Yes, in normal size is a little hard to see but just press the ctrl key and scroll up to zoom in. The quality of the picture is good so even with a large zoom it can be readed perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asignacion.id_nivel` and `asignacion.id_asignatura` are dynamic types.

When you pass a dynamic type into any method as an argument, the return type of the method becomes dynamic instead of whatever MSDN says it is. You cannot use extension methods on dynamic types. `Count()` is an extension method on `Enumerable`. That's why you get the exception.

There are two ways to solve the problem and revert the return type to Enumerable. The first is to define it explicitly:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> data = db.Query(someSQL, parameterValue);
```

and the other is to cast the parameter to a non-dynamic type:

```
var data = db.Query(someSQL, (string)parameterValue);
```

And as Knox points out, you must use parameters rather than string.Format.

Comment: Mike, thanks by the explanation. Do you know if this is mentioned somewhere in MSDN? to have the veracity that this statement is always valid. I didn't use the normal parameters specification because a lot of times when for example the parameter is a string i have problems in the parsing step......'@i' is bad interpreted.....also when I have more than ten parameters ...and with String.Format i never had any problem....the msdn site for DataBase.Query is little poor...and don't explain any of the mentioned cases.

Comment: Better than MSDN, here it is from the mouth of the Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391115/what-causes-extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched-here

Answer (score 0):

The difference is debugger is due to dificultades has already evaluated
(`var c_dif = dificultades.Count();`).
Other two variables is not evaluated yet (linq deferred).
So debugger knows more about dificultades.

Comment: If I continue the execution an exception is thrown. Exactly in the highlighted line. Your answer don't respond why they are evaluated different. This queries are executed immediately not deferred.

Comment: Mmm, they looks like linq enumerables. dificultades is evaluated because of Count() on the previous line, the others are waiting for their Count(). I may be wrong, but it is plausible.

Comment: The easiest way to check it is to compare debugger values for difficultades before `var c_dif = dificultades.Count();` execution and after it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that habilidades and the other one have data?  I think it might be that db.Query is returning a null, meaning no rows returned, and then habilidades.Count can't execute because null doesn't have an object to execute against.  One way to test this outside the debugger is to do a db.QueryValue( "Select Count(*) from ...") and see if you're getting zero rows returned.

By the way, the database functions in C# build in the variable handling in a slightly shorter way than you have.  You can write

```
var ejes = db.Query( @"
        Select *  
        From asign  
        Where id_nivel = @0",   
        asignacion.id_nivel );
```

This technique is called parameterized SQL.  I'm only showing one parameter, but you will need more.  The @0, @1, @2, and so forth get replaced just like in a String.Format.