# Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to have DropDownListFor in MVC

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.TitleIds, new SelectList(ViewBag.TitleNames as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "TitleId", "Title.TitleText"), "No: " + ViewBag.MagNo, new { id = "TitleIds" })   
}
```

in Controller

```
public ActionResult ArticleList(int id)
{
    ArticleWriter_ViewModel viewModel = new ArticleWriter_ViewModel();
    Func<IQueryable<NumberTitle>, IOrderedQueryable<NumberTitle>> orderByFunc = null;
    Expression<Func<NumberTitle, bool>> filterExpr = null;
    if (id > 0)
    {
        filterExpr = p => p.MagazineId.Equals(id);
    }
    var wholeTitles = unitOfWork.NumberTitleRepository.Get(filterExpr,  orderByFunc, "Magazine,Title").ToList();          

    ViewBag.MagNo = wholeTitles[0].Magazine.MagNo.ToString();
    ViewBag.MagId = wholeTitles[0].Magazine.Id;
    ViewBag.TitleNames = wholeTitles;

    return View("../Panel/Magazine/ArticleList", "_BasicLayout", viewModel);
}
```

but I get this error

> '`System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Cinemavaadabiat.ViewModel.ArticleWriter_ViewModel>>`' has no applicable method named '`DropDownListFor`' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

I can't understand the error, what should I check for it?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You are using dynamic types in extension methods, which is not supported.

Cast the dynamic types to actual types, and it will work.

From what I see now, I'd say:

```
(string) ViewBag.MagNo
```

Which would result in

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.TitleIds, 
       new SelectList(ViewBag.TitleNames as System.Collections.IEnumerable, 
       "TitleId", "Title.TitleText"), 
       "No: " + (string) ViewBag.MagNo, 
       new { id = "TitleIds" })   
}
```

Comment: it says Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: @nnmmss then ViewBag.MagNo is not an int, but a string. Cast it to a string and you should be golden

Comment: This answer doesn't really address the real issue -- the code works in other projects without casting, just not in his -- likely there is some configuration missing and it's causing the compiler to be confused. -- Edit: Looks like @mkaj's answer addresses the actual issue.

Comment: Can I cast `ViewBag.MagNo` to a `bool?` type?

Comment: I was passing an integer. What I ended up doing (string)ViewBag.MyNumber.ToString(). Just adding ToString() or (string) throws exception. Yah I found that weird too.

Answer (score 48):

My fix for this problem was to add:

```
    @model MyModel
```

At the top of the partial control. I had forgotten it.

Comment: Thanks, I was migrating my views to other project and I forgot the @model, thks!

Comment: You also get this error if you use uppercase @Model instead of lowercase model.

Comment: Can you expand this answer a little?  What does "MyModel" refer to in this context?  What is the "partial control" you're referring to?

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the subject of MVC extension methods (which is how I ran across this question), I like to use Dapper's `connection.Query()` syntax which will return results as an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

It is also possible to use dynamic objects by:

- Calling the static method directly, per Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391292/188567):

  ```
  @model IEnumerable<dynamic>

  @PartialExtensions.Partial(Html, "~/link/to/_partialView.cshtml", Model)
  ```
- Wrapping it in a class.

  ```
  public class DynamicQueryResult
  {
      public dynamic QueryResults {get; set;}
  }
  ```

  Then in your MVC View:

  ```
  @model Namespace.DynamicQueryResult

  @Html.Partial("~/link/to/_partialView.cshtml", Model)
  ```