# Why don't dynamic objects and extension methods play nice?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime

The causes of the exception:

> Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Have been covered in several SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391115/what-causes-extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched-here/15391292#15391292) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932646/extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched) ).But no one has said why the Framework doesn't allow this:

---

### Example

```
public static class ExampleExtension
{
    public static string HelloWorld(this object o, object o2)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        dynamic dynamicObject = new object();

        //Exception
        new object().HelloWorld(dynamicObject);

        //No Exception
        ExampleExtension.HelloWorld(new object(), dynamicObject);
    }
}
```

---

> new object().HelloWorld(dynamicObject)` **is bad**

---

> ExampleExtension.HelloWorld(new object(), dynamicObject)` **is good**

---

### Why?

If extension methods are essentially just syntactic sugar for calling a static method, wouldn't `new object().HelloWolrd()` be converted to the compiler to `ExampleExtension.HelloWorld(new object())` anyway?  So why can't the `DLR` handle this?

Comment: Eric lippert has answered your question in suggested duplicate.