# Razor html helper parameter shows message about redundant conditional ternary expression usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, htmlextensions

Why there is a Visual Studio message about redundant conditional ternary expression usage, when there is a mouse over expression (also expression "true : false" has lower opacity). Does it tell me about i can write somehow less code to get what i want (if ViewBag.CMSClientStatus is equal to "Действующий", then check the radio)?

```
@Html.RadioButton("ClientStatus", "Real",  ViewBag.CMSClientStatus == "Действующий" ? true : false, new { @readonly = true })
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP2OL.jpg)

Comment: Why you even want to use ternary? do you miss parenthesis or something?

Comment: What is it that you are trying do do? Best guess is that you want to make the control readonly if `ViewBag.CMSClientStatus == "Действующий"` (if that's the case then it would need to be `@Html.RadioButton("ClientStatus", "Real",  ViewBag.CMSClientStatus == "Действующий" ? new { @readonly = true }: null)`

Answer (score 2):

Expression `ViewBag.CMSClientStatus == "Действующий"` already returns `true` or `false`. Ternary operator adds nothing to your logic, it's redundant as Visual Studio suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
ViewBag.CMSClientStatus == "Действующий" ? true : false
```

Just use:

```
ViewBag.CMSClientStatus == "Действующий"
```

The equality operator (`==`) already returns `true` or `false`, so no need for a conditional operator.

Comment: wait. this is the most simple thing in c#. how could he write code when he dont know `==` returns true and false (and he knows ternary ?!). i think he miss parenthesis or something

Answer (score 0):

I've write as it was suggested in previous two answers. But then an error came out: "Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvmoe.jpg)

Answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932646/extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched). I need cast the dynamic type to Boolean type.
My final entry is:

```
@Html.RadioButton("ClientStatus", "Потенциальный",  (bool) (ViewBag.CMSClientStatus == "Потенциальный"), new { @readonly = true })
```