# How to create MVC Extension Method for Dynamic type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

I want to create Extension methods for dynamic type, but for some or the other reason i get error while compiling the code. below is my code sample
The method which i am using is

```
public List<State> getStates()
{

    return new List<State>(){
         new State{StateID="1",StateName="Tamil Nadu"},
         new State{StateID="2",StateName="Assam"},
         new State{StateID="3",StateName="Andra"},
         new State{StateID="4",StateName="bihar"},
         new State{StateID="5",StateName="Bengal"},            
    };
}
```

and my extension method is

```
public static class helper
{
     public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getIntoDropDownState(this List<dynamic> data,string textField,string valueField)
    {
        return data.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.textField,
            Value = x.valueField
        });
    }
}
```

My compilation error which i get is

> Compiler Error Message: CS1928:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   does not contain a definition for 'getIntoDropDownState' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'LearnAuthentication.Controllers.helper.getIntoDropDownState(System.Collections.Generic.List,
>   string, string)' has some invalid arguments

I want to use the Extension method like this, and I am facing error

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateID, new LearnAuthentication.Controllers.Address().getStates().getIntoDropDownState("StateName", "StateID"), "Select State", 0)
```

can anyone help

Comment: This code compiles for me.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @stephen.vakil hi i have updated the error, please have a look. thank you

Comment: @LijinJohn, That extension method is not going to do what you describe. You could use reflection and generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extension method in your example is not going to do what you describe. You could use reflection and generics.

```
public static class helper {
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getIntoDropDownState<T>(this List<T> data, string textField, string valueField) where T : class {
        var type = typeof(T);

        var textPropertyInfo = type.GetProperty(textField);
        var valuePropertyInfo = type.GetProperty(valueField);

        return data.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
            Text = (string)textPropertyInfo.GetValue(x),
            Value = (string)valuePropertyInfo.GetValue(x)
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a unit test for the extension method

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod() {
        //Arrange
        var data = getStates();

        //Act
        var result = data.getIntoDropDownState("StateName", "StateID");

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        var first = result.First();
        Assert.AreEqual(data[0].StateName, first.Text);
        Assert.AreEqual(data[0].StateID, first.Value);
    }

    public List<State> getStates() {

        return new List<State>(){
             new State{StateID="1",StateName="Tamil Nadu"},
             new State{StateID="2",StateName="Assam"},
             new State{StateID="3",StateName="Andra"},
             new State{StateID="4",StateName="bihar"},
             new State{StateID="5",StateName="Bengal"},            
        };
    }

    public class State {
        public string StateID { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Or you could forego reflection and use `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList` which does the heavy reflection lifting for you

```
public static class helper {
    public static IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> getIntoDropDownState<T>(this List<T> data, string textField, string valueField) where T : class {

        return new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(data, valueField, textField);

    }
}
```

Comment: i guess this is the only way we can make it possible. thank you for the time. I actually wanted to create a method by calling which a dropdown could be easily get bind in MVC

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic types in extension methods is not supported.
Cast the dynamic types to actual types, and it will work.
For more details check the below URL,
[Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932646/extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched)

Comment: i have updated my code can you please have a look at it, thank you