# MVC HtmlHelper extension method not found unless a cast is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I've defined an extension method called `BootstrapDropDownFor` which has a definition of

```
public static IHtmlString BootstrapDropDownFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, dynamic options, string defaultOption)
```

When trying to use it in a `.cshtml` file

```
@Html.BootstrapDropDownFor(m => m.RequestType, ViewBag.RequestTypes, "-- Select --")
```

I get the following error:

```
'HtmlHelper<WebPermissionModel>' does not contain a definition for 'BootstrapDropDownFor' and the best extension method overload 'HtmlHelpers.BootstrapDropDownFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>, dynamic, string, string)' requires a receiver of type 'HtmlHelper<TModel>'
```

However, by adding a cast to the `options` parameter, as below, I can get rid of the error.

```
@Html.BootstrapDropDownFor(m => m.RequestType, (object) ViewBag.RequestTypes, "-- Select --")
```

How come adding a cast fixes this issue?

Comment: `dynamic` types in extension methods are not supported (`ViewBag` is `dynamic`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamic is not supported in extension, check these:

[Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932646/extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched)

[Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object/5311527#5311527)

[What causes "extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched" here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391115/what-causes-extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched-here)

You must cast dynamic type explicitly before you pass it to method

change dynamic parameter to object or exact type: `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

`public static IHtmlString BootstrapDropDownFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> options, string defaultOption = "-- select --")`

Comment: Same error. It looks like no matter what I set `options`'s type to be, it will always throw that error. I'm not a fan of the second one either as the way the function works allows it to be many different types.

Comment: ANSWER UPDATED. no matter what object will be in dynamic, it will be converted  to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> inside your extension. why not explicitly declare parameter as IEnumerable<SelectListItem> since it's the data that dropdown excepts. and "dynamic" could confuse teammate: what should be in dynamic object?