# 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' has no applicable method named

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamicobject

I'm trying to create a response which sends the `HttpStatusCode` along with a `dynamic` object like this:

```
var t = _rep.GetOrders(params, sft);
...........
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Enumerable.Select(t, 
  (Func<Order, dynamic>)(x =>
    new
    {
       x.Id,
       x.Name,
       .....
    })));
```

But it gives me this error message:

> 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' has no applicable method named
>   'CreateResponse' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting
>   the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the
>   extension method syntax.

I don't quite understand what it's saying, or what I'm doing wrong here.

Can anyone shine some light on this matter please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes "extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched" here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391115/what-causes-extension-methods-cannot-be-dynamically-dispatched-here)

Comment: Extension methods and dynamic objects do not work together.

Comment: It's pointing you to a workaround - instead of doing `Request.CreateResponse` you can call the static method in a non-extension way `HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse`.

Comment: that should be an answer

Comment: Yes, the question is very old and the author may not pay attention, However, adding the method like this HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse.(request, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) exposed the reason why it was not able to see the extension methods. It pointed that I needed package Micorsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client that was not imported because I was working in a ClassLibrary type of project. After adding the required packagem, I was able to revert the change obviously and it was able to see the extension method.