# C# dynamic and working with IEnumerable collections

Tags: c#, dynamic

After encountering some problems with [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) today, I decided to create a simple test program to illustrate the problem. I wonder, what's the mistake I'm doing in this code:

```
var list = new List<string>
               {
                   "Hey"
               };

dynamic data = list.Select(x => x);

var count = data.Count();
```

The last line throws an error: **'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count'**

**Why is the "data" treated as an object?** Does this problem occur because I'm calling an extension method?

The following code works:

```
var list = new List<string>
               {
                   "Hey"
               };

dynamic data = list.Select(x => x);

foreach (var s in data)
{
}
```

**Why in this case "data" is correctly treated as IEnumerable?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extension method and dynamic object in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that extension methods do not work on dynamic objects (see [Jon' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311527/804545)). However, you can call those directly as static methods:

```
var count = Enumerable.Count(data); // works
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's because `Count()` is an extension method.

> extension methods aren't supported by dynamic typing in the form of
>   extension methods, i.e. called as if they were instance methods. *([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp))*

`foreach (var s in data)` works, because `data` **has to** implements `IEnumerable` to be a `foreach` source - there is `(IEnumerable)data` conversion performed during execution.

You can see that mechanish when trying to do following:

```
dynamic t = 1;

foreach (var i in t)
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

There is an exception thrown at runtime: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`