# extension is not recognized on dynamic field

Tags: c#, dynamic, decimal, extension-methods

I used this extension on decimal fields:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    static System.Globalization.CultureInfo _cultInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    public static string ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal(this decimal source)
    {
        return source.ToString(_cultInfo);
    }
}
```

But when I have a dynamic parameter, that contains a class type with decimals in it, I cannot use the extension on those fields.

Test setup:

```
public class TestDecimalPropClass
{
    public decimal prop1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prop2 { get; set; }
}

private void TryExtensionOnDynamicButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestDecimalPropClass _testDecimalPropClass = new TestDecimalPropClass { prop1 = 98765.432M, prop2 = 159.753M };
    TestExtension(_testDecimalPropClass);
}

private void TestExtension(dynamic mySource)
{
    decimal hardDecimal = 123456.789M;
    string resultOutOfHardDecimal = hardDecimal.ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal();

    decimal prop1Decimal = mySource.prop1;
    string resultOutOfProp1Decimal = prop1Decimal.ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal();

    string resultOutOfProp2 = mySource.prop2.ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal();
}}
```

both resultOutOfHardDecimal and resultOutOfProp1Decimal return a correct string value, but when the code hits mySource.prop2.ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal(), I get this error:"'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal'", while prop2 is of decimal type.

Any thoughts?

Kind regards,

Matthijs

Comment: Why not use `Extensions.ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal(mySource.prop2)` directly ?

Comment: Yeah, quit stupid isn't it. I just didn't think about it. (coffee is almost done). But thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extension method and dynamic object in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension methods don't work with dynamics.

Because the C# compiler can't resolve the type of `mySource.prop2` at build time, it can't know that it can use the extension method.

However, you can still explicitly call the method:

```
string resultOutOfProp2 = Extensions.ConvertToStringWithPointDecimal(mySource.prop2);
```

(like any static method)

See also: [Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp) with answers from Jon Skeet and Eric Lippert.

Comment: Both you and Alessandro D'Andria have got a point here...I need some extra coffee :-) thanks