# Why is Extension Method Not Found in MVC4 Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Given the following string extension method

```
namespace JHS.ExtensionMethods
{
  public static class StringExtensions
  {
    public static string ToUSAPhone(this String str)
    {
      return String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Double.Parse(str));
    }
  }
}
```

A @using statement was added to the MVC4 Razor view

```
@using JHS.ExtensionMethods;
```

and the following string value calls the extension method

```
@Model.producer.phone.ToUSAPhone()
```

which results in the following error

```
'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToUSAPhone'
```

I also tried putting the namespace in the web.config of the /Views folder and receive the same error.

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="JHS.ExtensionMethods"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

I have verified the extension method works by putting the same call in a C# class

```
string test=producer.phone.ToUSAPhone();
```

It seems the reference to the extension method is not available in the MVC4 Razor view but I can't figure out why?

Comment: Could you show some more code of the view? You might have some syntax errors. Are you also sure that `phone` is of type `string` and is not `null`?

Comment: Side note: Parsing a number, which is *by definition* integer, into a `double` is just *insane*…

Comment: Second side note: semicolon is not needed after `@using` clausule.

Comment: why are you taking an input string and parsing it as a double only to cast the double back to a string in the return?

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening your View? Sometimes IntelliSense acts weird.

Answer (score 40):

This happens if the type you are trying to use the extension method on is actually a `dynamic`. Check to see if the exception is being generated by the CSharp RuntimeBinder. If so, you can either use the method as a common or garden static method:

```
@StringExtensions.ToUSAPhone(Model.producer.phone)
```

Or you can cast the value to a string:

```
@(((string)Model.producer.phone).ToUSAPhone())
```

[According to Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp) (formerly of MSFT):

> The reason behind the fact that dynamics do not support extension
>   types is because in regular, non-dynamic code extension methods work
>   by doing a full search of all the classes known to the compiler for a
>   static class that has an extension method that match. The search goes
>   in order based on the namespace nesting and available "using"
>   directives in each namespace.
>
> That means that in order to get a dynamic extension method invocation
>   resolved correctly, somehow the DLR has to know at runtime what all
>   the namespace nestings and "using" directives were in your source
>   code. There is no mechanism handy for encoding all that information
>   into the call site.

Comment: The error OP quoted is: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToUSAPhone'`. Razor already knows it's a `string`.

Comment: Actually, Razor doesn't know anything about data types. It's a templating language, not a compiler. If the type is dynamic, as I said in my answer, it is not a string. The error message that the OP reports is being generated by the RuntimeBinder. See Eric Lippert's explanation of what's going on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: I don't actually know for certain that it is a RuntimeBinder error. But the error message and description of the symptoms certainly smells like one. Hopefully @ChrisP will come back and provide some confirmation of further details.

Comment: TL;DR.  Because razor and the associated tools are really really buggy.

Comment: I know it is an old thread but since nobody mentioned it, solution #1 (@StringExtensions.ToUSAPhone(Model.producer.phone)) does work.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just if the type you're calling the extension method on is dynamic, but if anything in the expression is dynamic and not cast.

eg this is clearly dynamic:

```
@ViewBag.ToJSON()
```

But I first thought Mike's answer did not apply to me because I was doing this :

```
@(ViewBag.UserProfile.GetJSONProfile().ToJSON())
```

where `ToJSON()` is my extension method and `GetJSONProfile()` just returns `object`.

I was just spacing out and being stupid but wanted to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Build your project before adding your custom namespace for the extentions to your View.

Answer (score 0):

There may be yet another trivial reason for this and it happened to me.

The file that I created my extension in had "Content" as value for Build Action property on VS file properties pane.

Switching it to "Compile" immediately fixed the issue, naturally...

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same problem with the same error message, but in my case in some weird way, i fixed it by putting the ";"

so what was

```
@{var subti = item.subtitle.Truncate(18)}
```

was fixed with the ;

```
@{var subti = item.subtitle.Truncate(18);}
```

this maybe could help someone