# Can I have extension methods for ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, extension-methods

Can I make `extension methods` for [`ViewBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), or I should use `ViewData` instead?

I tried creating `extension methods` for `object` since that is ViewBag's type, but it didn't work.

```
public static void AddUserData(this object ViewBag)
{

}
```

Can someone please explain why we can't have extension methods for ViewBag?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why doesn't your code work?

Comment: take a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255688/why-is-extension-method-not-found-in-mvc4-razor-view especially he first answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `ViewBag` is a [`dynamic type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx), [`extension methods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb383977.aspx) will not be picked up on their properties without casting to the appropriate type first.

I recommend you to reduce use of `ViewBag` to avoid having to cast everywhere. Instead you can use strongly typed view models for views.