# Asp.net MVC not finding extension method, despite putting in Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a String extension method. It is under the namespace `MyApp`. It worked in all C# classes, but won't work in MVC Razor views.

I tried adding to one and both Web.config files (on in root, and one is views), under the `<namespaces>` sections, but it just won't find the extension method. I tried adding under the `<system.web>` and `<system.web.webPages.razor>` sections, but still won't work.

I am using MVC 3, .Net 4.

Here's the extension:

```
namespace MyApp
{    
    public static class StringExtension
    {
        // ...
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public static string FormatWith(this string target, params object[] args)
        {
            Check.Argument.IsNotEmpty(target, "target");

            return string.Format(Constants.CurrentCulture, target, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the web.config piece:

```
<namespaces>
    <!-- The extension method is in this namespace: -->
    <add namespace="MyApp" />
</namespaces>
```

And:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="MyApp" />
      <add namespace="MyApp.Web" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

The error I keep getting is:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'FormatWith' and no
>   extension method 'FormatWith' accepting a first argument of type
>   'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I tried adding `@using MyApp` at the top of the view, but it still shows same error.

I have used this extension in a nearly identical project using the same approach and it works fine. The other project is MVC 4 and .net 4.5.

Comment: Is the method & class `public`?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question.

Comment: Just to troubleshoot that it is even accessable add the `using <namespace>` to the top of the view and see if the extension is available. if yes then we can move forward from there.

Comment: Also show the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` as it is now in the `Views/web.config` file

Comment: Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255688/why-is-extension-method-not-found-in-mvc4-razor-view?rq=1

Comment: I updated question. I have added the `using MyApp` to the view, and it still won't find the extension method. However, the controller for the view finds the extension just fine.