# Method member access on dynamic object invokes TryGetMember

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, expandoobject

I have a custom dynamic objects which is internally just a dictionary, but allows to access it's values as if their being compile time properties.

It's (more or less) just this:

```
public class Dummy : DynamicObject, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _values...

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = _values[binder.Name];
        return true;
    }
    ...
```

Setting and getting 'properties' works fine, but since my object technically implements `IEnumerable<'1>`, I'd like to call methods from `IEnumerable<'1>` on it.

However, whenever I call e.g. `Count()`, `TryGetMember` gets invoked which of course doesn't make sense:

```
The key 'Count()' was not present in the dictionary.
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem.  Can you show how you're calling `Count()`?

Comment: Also, `Count` is not a method on `IEnumerable` - it is an _extension method_ that the compiler translates into a call to the static method `Enumerable.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you can't use extension methods with dynamic objects using the normal syntax. You can use `Enumerable.Count(dummyInstance);` though but I doubt this is what you want.

See [[Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object-in-c-sharp]) for details.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand this correctly. I always thought extensions methods are just syntactical sugar that translate to a static method call with the member being called on as the first parameter? So list.Count() becomes Enumerator.Count(list) after compiling, so this shouldn't have anything to do with the instance being dynamic, or object, or whatever?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's syntactic sugar. Which means it's done at compile time. It seems like the compiler should know that you're instantiating a Dummy class and therefore should treat the dynamic object as an IEnumerable during compilation but it doesn't actually do this and thus it doesn't know which static method to call. Does that make sense?