# Using Extension Methods on Underlying Type Contained by an 'object' at Runtime

Tags: c#, extension-methods, object-type

I asked a [question recently on the same project I'm working on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578105/design-pattern-or-accepted-solutions-for-avoiding-switching-on-types), but this is a specific question regarding extension methods and the object type.

The following code doesn't work:

```
object ProcessField(byte [] buff, int position, Dictionary<int, Type> fields)
{
    int field = buff[position];
    position++;

    // Create an instance of the specified type.
    object value = Activator.CreateInstance(fields[field]);
    // Call an extension method for the specified type.
    value.DoSomething();

    return value;
}

public static void DoSomething(this Int32 value)
{
    // Do Something
}

public static void DoSomething(this Int16 value)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

The compiler gives this error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DoSomething' and the best extension method overload 'DoSomething()' has some invalid arguments in blah blah...

It seems the extension method isn't bound at runtime, even though the underlying type is System.Int32 or System.Int16 (verified at runtime).

Is there any way to make this work (using extension methods)?  Is it just code semantics, or is it just not possible on an 'object' without casting it at design time?

Comment: Well of course it doesn't work, you're calling a short/int extension method on an `object`. What if the object is really of type string?

Comment: Just cast it before calling the method, if you're sure its an int/short.

Comment: "It seems the extension method isn't bound at runtime" - correct. Extension methods are *compile-time* syntactic sugar.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, I would expect it to throw an exception at runtime if the extension method didn't exist for the underlying type.

Comment: @Mephy, I don't know if it's an int/short at design time...  That was just an example.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I see...  It's the same reason I can't use extension methods with the dynamic keyword, I guess.

Is it possible, via some kind of magical run-time cast, to access the extension methods for the underlying object type?

Comment: @tfjield To call the Extension methods at runtime with dynamic you call them via plain static method style: `ExtensionClass.DoSomething(value)`. There is no way to invoke them via instance method syntax dynamically.

Comment: @mikez Oh, it's that simple!  Thank you.  I hadn't realized that an extension method allowed being called as you suggested.  If I know the type at design time, I can call it as an extension method, and if I don't know it at runtime, I can use the static method style, and there's no need to create methods with different declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ...uhhh... really bad, but you can achieve what you want like this using `dynamic`.  But don't do it.  It's really bad.

```
object ProcessField(byte [] buff, int position, Dictionary<int, Type> fields)
{
    int field = buff[position];
    position++;  // this line really does absolutely nothing

    // dynamic is magic!
    dynamic value = Activator.CreateInstance(fields[field]);

    DoSomething(value);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: LOL, it's funny you say that...  That's how I ended up doing it in my other post!  But I realized there that I didn't explore fully whether it was possible to do it with extension methods, rather than polymorphic functions.

Comment: After reading mike z's comment above, does my previous comment even make sense?  Is there any difference between an extension method and a polymorphic function, other than the syntax?

Comment: Extension methods are just regular static methods.  And you can use them exactly as such.