# Design issue with generic/inheritance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I can't find a good solution to solve a design issue i'm facing. Currently I'm designing a system supposed to parse query string.

Each parser must implement the interface IQueryParser:

```
public interface IQueryParser
{
    Query Parse();
}
```

When I receive a HTTP request, I try to find a parser able to parse it using a factory. QueryContext is just a simpler version of HttpRequest

```
public interface IQueryParserFactory
{
    void Register<TQueryParser>(Func<QueryContext, bool> predicate)
        where TQueryParser : IQueryParser;
    IQueryParser Create(QueryContext context);
}

public class QueryParserFactory : IQueryParserFactory
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<QueryContext, bool>> _parsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<QueryContext, bool>>();

    public void Register<TQueryParser>(Func<QueryContext, bool> predicate)
        where TQueryParser : IQueryParser
        => _parsers.AddOrUpdate(typeof(TQueryParser), predicate, (key, oldValue) => predicate);

    public IQueryParser Create(QueryContext context)
        => (from kpv in _parsers
            where kpv.Value.Invoke(context)
            select (IQueryParser)Activator.CreateInstance(kpv.Key, context)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Parsers may require extra dependencies and I don't know how to inject them into the parser. Let's say we have the following parser.. How can i know what concrete implementation of IOperatorParser do i need?

```
public class QueryParser : IQueryParser
{
    private readonly QueryContext _context;

    public QueryParser(QueryContext context, IOperatorParser parser)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Query Parse()
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

I would need some kind of dependency injection. The problem is that I instantiate object myself and that I also pass the QueryContext at the runtime. Any hint/idea on how i can redesign my app to handle my use case?

Thank you,
Sebastien

Comment: Actually one solution could be to instantiate all parsers and pass them to the factory. Then each parser would need to implement a CanParse method. Not ideal but would do the trick? Any better option?

Comment: I've just read a good post regarding injecting runtime values (https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). Based on this, you might want to rethink your injection of the context via the constructor.

Comment: I've used your `CanParse()` solution before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578105/design-pattern-or-accepted-solutions-for-avoiding-switching-on-types/28580610#28580610). It works but I'm sure there's a better way out there somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `QueryContext context` is runtime data and shouldn't be injected into your objects.

You can either use the `CanParse` solution you mentioned, or you can use this alternative:

```
public interface IQueryParser
{
    Maybe<Query> Parse(QueryContext context);
}
```

The `Maybe<T>` struct is used to support a return value of "no value" (this is more readable and honest that returning a `null` `Query` for "no value") . See more on this here: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/13/functional-c-non-nullable-reference-types/

The implementer of this interface is expected to return a "no value" if it cannot parse.

Now, the consumer get's a collection of already built stateless parsers like this:

```
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly IQueryParser[] parsers;

    public Consumer(IQueryParser[] parsers)
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

And each time it is invoked, it tries all parsers until it finds one that can parse the query:

```
var result =
    parsers
        .Select(x => x.Parse(context))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.HasValue); //the default of the `Maybe` struct is a "no value"

if(result.HasValue) //some parse was able to parse
   //...
else
   //..
```