# How and why inline helper methods evaluating types at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

As you know, we can create two types of ***Helper methods*** in ASP.NET MVC:

- *Inline helper methods*
- *External helper methods*

And now, let's say I am passsing data from the controller to the view by using the `ViewBag` object. Like that:

```
ViewBag.Fruits = new string[] {"Apple", "Orange", "Pear"};
```

And I have defined such **inline helper method** in the view:

```
@helper ListArrayItemsInline(string[] items)
{
    ...
}
```

And here is an **external helper method** which takes a string array as an input:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ListArrayItemsExternal(this HtmlHelper html, string[] list)
{
    ...
}
```

And the *difference* is that, I must cast `ViewBag.Fruits` to `string[]` if I want to use external one. Yes, everything is right here. But, this is not the case with the inline one. As I see, it evaluates types at runtime.

```
// external one, we must cast 
@Html.ListArrayItemsExternal((string[])ViewBag.Fruits) 

// internal one, works just fine
@ListArrayItemsInline(ViewBag.Fruits)
```

Could you please explain me, how and why inline helper methods evaluating types at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is solely in the **syntax** you use to invoke the helper: `ListArrayItemsInline` is a normal method, but `ListArrayItemsExternal` is an extension method. If you attempt to invoke `ListArrayItemsExternal` as an extension method without casting the argument, then the compiler gives you this error message:

> CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'ListArrayItemsExternal' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

The error message suggests two options for resolving the error:

**Option 1.** Cast the dynamic argument:

```
@Html.ListArrayItemsExternal((string[])ViewBag.Fruits)
```

**Option 2.** Call `ListArrayItemsExternal` using normal method syntax, in which case you don't have to cast the dynamic argument:

```
MyHelpers.ListArrayItemsExternal(Html, ViewBag.Fruits)
```

The second option demonstrates that types *can* be resolved at run time for external helper methods. You just have to use the right syntax.

As for *why* extension methods can't be dynamically dispatched, check out [this answer by Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313149/1127114).

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I got it. So, the reason of this difference is not if the method is internal or external. But, if the method is extension or not. Yes? Because, extension methods can't be dynamically dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag` property offers a flexible way to pass data to the view.The property of ViewBag is defined as *dynamic type*.

```
public dynamic ViewBag{get;}
```

When a .NET compiler encounters a dynamic type,it emits a special chunk of code instead of simply evaluating the expression.Such special chunk of code passes the expression to the **Dynamic Language Runtime(DLR)** for a run-time evaluation.

In other words any expression based on the dynamic type is compiled at run time.Any member set or read out of ViewBag is always accepted by the compiler but not actually evaluated until execution.

Comment: But, why it is not the case with **external helper methods?**

Comment: He did answer. Inline methods are parsed by the DLR, while external methods use static typing resolution to solve the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it from your answer. But, I have understood what is the exact difference after reading other answer. Anyway, it was also really very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @MariusUngureanu We can say this, but the reason of this difference is not if the method is internal or external. But, if the method is extension or not. Because, extension methods can't be dynamically dispatched.