# Creating a dynamic extension method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Is it possible to workaround this error:

```
public static class LayoutExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies if an object is DynamicNull or just has a null value.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsDynamicNull(this dynamic obj)
    {
        return (obj == null || obj is DynamicNull);
    }
```

Compile time

```
Error: The first parameter of an extension method 
       cannot be of type 'dynamic'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311527/613130

When you use a `dynamic` object, you can't call an extension method through the "extension method syntax". To make it clear:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
int first1 = arr.First(); // extension method syntax, OK
int first2 = Enumerable.First(arr); // plain syntax, OK
```

Both of these are ok, but with `dynamic`

```
dynamic arr = new int[5];
int first1 = arr.First(); // BOOM!
int first2 = Enumerable.First(arr); // plain syntax, OK
```

This is logical if you know how `dynamic` objects work. A `dynamic` variable/field/... is just an `object` variable/field/... (plus an attribute) that the C# compiler knows that should be treated as `dynamic`. And what does "treating as dynamic" means? It means that generated code, instead of using directly the variable, uses reflection to search for required methods/properties/... inside the type of the object (so in this case, inside the `int[]` type). Clearly reflection can't go around all the loaded assemblies to look for extension methods that could be anywhere.

Comment: with the "this object" approach, what will not work: the intellisense or runtime error?

Comment: @Serge *When you use a dynamic object, you can't call an extension method through the "extension method syntax".* It is irrelevant the type of extension method. If you have `dynamic b = something;` you can't use **any** `b.ExtensionMethod()`

Comment: what do you mean "I can't"? I can, I just ask what will be the result! ;)

Comment: @Serge You get a `RuntimeBinderException` thrown in your face. BOOM

Answer (score 1):

All classes derived by object class. Maybe try this code

```
public static bool IsDynamicNull(this object obj)
{
    return (obj == null || obj is DynamicNull);
}
```

Comment: yes... is cool... but don't really need to do `"Hello".IsDynamicNull()`... or `myInt.IsDynamicNull`... I would like to limit this behavior for dynamic variables... could be strings, sure... but declared as dynamic....

Comment: @Jacek Won't work... See https://ideone.com/HrfsF0 You can't use directly extension methods on `dynamic` objects (see (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5311527/613130)

Comment: @xanatos can you suggest how to save this issue, as i am facing the problem of RuntimeBinderException, i have created extensions for the object class, i was expecting that during runtime it will be able to find the extension and be able to execute it but unfortunately i got the RuntimeBinderException, any suggestions what to do other than passing the variable as a parameter ??

Comment: @SyedAbdulQadeer You can't do it. The response from Skeet in the linked post is clear enough. dynamic and extension methods don't play well together. Eric Lippert's response explains why.