# "ERROR Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicInstanceHelper" error logged every 30 seconds

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I am currently experiencing the following error in Umbraco:

```
2016-12-12 11:45:56,665 [P10884/D3/T68] ERROR Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicInstanceHelper - An error occurred finding and executing extension method "FirstOrDefault" for type "Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContent". Types searched for extension methods were Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContent.
    System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Umbraco.Web.Models.DynamicPublishedContent.FirstOrDefault' not found.
       at Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicInstanceHelper.FindAndExecuteExtensionMethod[T](IRuntimeCacheProvider runtimeCache, T thisObject, Object[] args, String name, IEnumerable`1 findMethodsOnTypes)
       at Umbraco.Core.Dynamics.DynamicInstanceHelper.TryInvokeMember[T](IRuntimeCacheProvider runtimeCache, T thisObject, InvokeMemberBinder binder, Object[] args, IEnumerable`1 findExtensionMethodsOnTypes)
```

It is logged about every 30 seconds, over and over, all day. I was wondering if anyone knows what this means? The site seems to be running fine, but I am slightly concerned as none of my other Umbraco installations have this particular error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling extension methods on a dynamic. See these posts for details. They were helpful for me.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135160/shortcomings-of-using-dynamic-types-in-c
- [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135160/shortcomings-of-using-dynamic-types-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743568/creating-a-dynamic-extension-method-in-c)

You should be able to use

```
Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(myListOfDynamicStuff);
```

instead of

```
myListOfDynamicStuff.FirstOrDefault();
```

The extension methods are bound at compile time. In order to be bound correctly, the types would have to match up. In your case, your `myListOfDynamicStuff` variable would need to implement `IEnumerable`. However, your `myListOfDynamicStuff` is a dynamic, and the types don't match. I like to use the more strongly typed IPublishedContent in umbraco. You can get the current page like `Model.Content` and you can use the umbracoHelper, `Umbraco.TypedContent()` to get nodes by id.

Umbraco has implemented its own FirstOrDefault for dynamics that isn't an extension method. My guess is that you are either missing a dll, a using statement, or a reference of some sort in your web.config. I would download a vanilla copy of umbraco that matches your site, and do a compare of all the files. My favorite tool for this is [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). Pay special attention to the dlls in the /bin and anything missing from either the root Web.config or the Web.config in the /Views directory.