# Why extension methods should not be called on dynamic objects?

Tags: c#, dynamic, extension-methods

Given the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class ExtenionPerson
{
    public static string GetPersonName(this Person person)
    {
        return person.Name;
    }
}
```

where a person has a name, and there is an extension method to get the person name. Now if I do:

```
dynamic person = new Person { Name = "Jon" };
var name = person.GetPersonName();
```

there will be thrown a RuntimeBinderException.

I know that extension methods should not be invoked on dynamic objects, but why is this now allowed? My guess is that because extension methods are resolved at compile-time and dynamic objects are resolved at runtime, as specified by the intelisense. How right is this?

Comment: You can use the static class call `ExtenionPerson.GetPersonName(person);` Do you really need to use dynamic here ? Or you're just writing this code as an example for this issue ?

Comment: @user3185569 , I know this is how it can be invoked, but thank you for pointing this!

Comment: Who can explain that better than Eric Lippert: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5313149/3185569

Comment: @user3185569 I have read only the Jon's answer, didn't saw the second one. Thank you for flagging the question, I will close it myself :)