# Why does dynamic.ToString() return something between a string and not a string?

Tags: c#, dynamic, tostring

I use a type derived from a `DynamicObject` as a builder for some strings. At the end I call `ToString` to get the final result.

At this point I thought it would give me a normal string but this string is somehow strange. It behaves like one when I use string functions on it but it behaves like I don't know actually what, something neither a string nor a dynamic.

---

This is how I implemented `ToString` on my builder

```
public class Example : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.ReturnType == typeof(string))
        {
            result = ToString();
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }   

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I run it like this

```
dynamic example = new Example();
Console.WriteLine(example.ToString().ToUpper());
```

the result is correct: `USERQUERY+EXAMPLE` (when executed in LINQPad)

However if I call the second line like this

```
Console.WriteLine(example.ToString().Extension());
```

where

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static string Extension(this string str)
    {
        return str.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

the application crashes with a `RuntimeBinderException` saying

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Extension'

but if I cast the result it works again

```
Console.WriteLine(((string)example.ToString()).Extension());
```

---

Maybe one more example.

```
Console.WriteLine((string)example); // UserQuery+Example
```

but

```
Console.WriteLine(example); // DynamicObject UserQuery+Example
```

You can actually never be sure what you'll get until you cast it to string.

---

Why is this happening and is there a way to avoid the additional cast and get somehow a *real* string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `ToString` called on `dynamic` is typed to return `dynamic` and not `string`:

```
dynamic example = new Example();
// test will be typed as dynamic
var test = example.ToString();
```

When you call `ToUpper` on `test` it will use dynamic binding and resolve to `string.ToUpper` at runtime. You have to cast to a concrete type to *escape* dynamic typing.

Extension methods is a compile-time feature and as such is not supported by `dynamic` typing *as extension method*. You can still call it using regular static method invocation syntax.

```
Extensions.Extension(example.ToString());
```

But again - `example.ToString()` will return `dynamic` and type binding will happen at runtime to check if it can be used as a parameter to `Extensions.Extension` call. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311527/1163867) for details.

Comment: ok, I understand why an extension does not work directly on a dynamic object but this does not work either `example.ToString().ToLower().Extension()` so this means that as long as I don't cast it to a concrete type I'll always get `dynamic` back no matter if the method retuned `int` or `string` or anything?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. You need to cast to some specific type to escape dynamic typing. That cast can be either explicit (by using `(string)`) or implicit by assigning dynamically-typed expression to a statically-typed variable or passing it as parameter into a statically-typed method.