# Case-Insensitive List.Contains(): No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#

C# Case-Insensitive List.Contains(): No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments

Got compiler error if we do

```
list.Contains(stringToSearchDynamic.ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

But compiles OK if we put actual string

```
list.Contains(stringToSearch, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Is this a compiler bug ?

Code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");

string stringToSearch = "OnE";
dynamic stringToSearchDynamic = "OnE";

//compiles OK
bool isContained = list.Contains(stringToSearch, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);


//Does NOT compile
isContained = list.Contains(stringToSearchDynamic.ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41415574/2794280

Comment: First of all, there's no need to use `ToString()` with a *string*. It's essentially a no-op that returns the string itself. If the string passed as an object, a simple cast is enough

Comment: It was just to make it clearer

Comment: @LydonCh a cast is always clearer. In this case, it would avoid the problem altogether

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct, a cast works too, as it tells the compiler what type it is. so it worked if I do list.Contains( (stringToSearchDynamic as string), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of a `dynamic` expression is also dynamic. Since you have a dynamic variable the type of `variable.ToString` is resolved at runtime, not at compile time. So it's treated as `dynamic` and compiler can't find a `Contains` method that takes `dynamic` as first argument.

You can cast to `string` as suggested in the comments, it works because casting is a compile-time thing and makes the compiler treat your variable as string.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos care to elaborate why?

Comment: The error text itself complains about `Contains` with two arguments, not about a type mismatch. Now that I think of it though,  `List.Contains()` uses only *one* argument. The OP is trying to use `Enumerable.Contains` but the compiler tries to use `List.Contains` instead

Comment: if you try with an int you still get the same error message: `list.Contains(2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

the compiler first searches instance methods, then extension methods, but since there is no method that takes dynamic as first argument it generates this error.

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple cast instead of `ToString()`. `ToString()` is essentially a no-op when applied to string instances anyway, it just returns the string itself. This compiles :

```
isContained = list.Contains((string)stringToSearchDynamic, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

**Explanation**

The original code is trying to use the [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension method which accepts a comparer as a second argument. The method's signature is `Contains<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)`. This means that the value to search itself must be TSource. In this case though, it's `dynamic` and unknown until runtime.

The compiler won't even try to use the extension method and try to find a Contains on List itself. What it finds though is a [List.Contains(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) that only accepts a *single* parameter and complains about multiple arguments

Answer (score 0):

I was using .NetFrameWork 4.7.2 and it was working fine but due to some reasons I had to use .NetFrameWork  2.0 and here it was giving similar error. so if you can use latest framework version it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have this error without a reasonable explanation, this behaviour has been changed from .NET standard 2.0 => 2.1. So if you're working in a .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Framework solution, this overload effectively does not exist.

Solution can be to use a workaround (eg. create your own extension method), or update the solution to .NET Standard 2.1. The second option sounds like a huge overkill for this use case, and will not be compatible with .NET Framework solutions.