# Linq Failure during Razor Page Rendering - No Definition for Any

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, dynamic

I'm receiving a `RuntimeBinderException` saying that `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` does not contain a definition for Any.  I have an `IEnumerable<string>` set within the dynamic ViewBag object called ValidationFailures.  However, this exception is thrown within the Razor page calling:

```
@if(ViewBag.ValidationFailures.Any())
{ ... }
```

The `IEnumerable` is added in my controller before returning the view as seen below:

```
ViewBag.ValidationFailures = TempData.ContainsKey("ValidationFailures")
                ? (IEnumerable<string>)TempData["ValidationFailures"]
                : Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

Normally, I'd chalk this up to missing a reference to Linq, but Linq is included within the web.config file within the View folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="myProject" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

For the hell of it I tried adding `@using System.Linq` to the top of the View as well, but this did not change the behavior.  Linq queries are working fine in other views, but this single view is giving me an issue.

What else could cause this exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties of ViewBag are `dynamic` and you can't call extension methods that way.

You can explicitly cast to your type to make it possible:

```
  @if(((IEnumerable<string>)ViewBag.ValidationFailures).Any())
```

See [Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object) for more info.

Comment: @JNYRanger linked q has detailed explanations, short - extensions methods are *not* method of object - so run-time type alone is not enough to find them.

Comment: Yep, I started reading and deleted my comment.  Thanks for the info!