# Error in cast List<dynamic> to IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>

Tags: c#, .net, list, dynamic, casting

I am facing an issue while casting an API response type. The API returns `List<object>` in a particular format code given below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;       
        
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic tupleStringList;
        tupleStringList = new List<dynamic>{Tuple.Create("a","b"),Tuple.Create("c","d")}; // this data will come API which I have no control
        IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>> test = (IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>) tupleStringList;// here we need to cast as another internal function which use it as IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is given below

> Run-time exception (line 9): Unable to cast object of type
> `` 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' `` to type
> `` 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String]]' ``.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'`` to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String]]'.]  
>    at CallSite.Target(Closure,CallSite,Object )  
>    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
>    at Program.Main() :line 9
> ```

Comment: Protip: don't use `dynamic` - nor `Tuple`. Is there a reason you're not using geneircs or `ValueTuple` instead?

Comment: _"The API returns `List<object>` in a particular format code"_ - why isn't it returning something strongly-typed instead of resorting to boxing everything with `Object`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `tupleStringList.Cast<Tuple<string, string>>()`, maybe like:

```
(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>)(tupleStringList.Cast<Tuple<string, string>>())
```

(This needs a `using System.Linq;` directive.)

Ralf has a point in the comments (see [Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/)): If extensions methods are not considered for the *binding* of a `dynamic` expression, cast to nongeneric `IEnumerable` first. For example:

```
var tupleStringListCast = (IEnumerable)tupleStringList;
var test = tupleStringListCast.Cast<Tuple<string, string>>();
```

Or call `Cast<TResult>()` with usual static call syntax:

```
var test = (IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>)(Enumerable.Cast<Tuple<string, string>>(tupleStringList));
```

---

However, it assumes the pairs are really of type `Tuple<,>`.

Comment: ... and tupleStringList not being a dynamic also ;)

Comment: @Ralf `tupleStringList` _was_ declared `dynamic`? What do you mean?

Comment: In the author example tupleStringList is defined as dynamic. You will have a hard time calling Cast on a dynamic. So in the cast crazyness needed you need to also cast tupleStringList to an IEnumerable<> to be able to call Cast.

Comment: @Ralf You can call anything on a `dynamic` at compile-time. Everything compiles. Because the _binding_ is postponed until the program runs (run-time). At that time, the extension method `.Cast<TResult>()` will apply if only the actual run-time type of `tupleStringList` is something that implement nongeneric `IEnumerable`. This will likely be the case. Another question is if the instances yielded are exactly of type `Tuple<string, string>`. Which is why I said "assumes" in my answer. The asker provided no details.

Comment: Interestingly Net 5 has a problem with finding the Cast method (RuntimeBinderException) while Net 6 has not as i thought. But your correct on that we are missing context for a "perfectly" fitting answer.

Comment: @Ralf You were more correct than I thought initially. I have updated my answer. Thanks.